# Representation of a linear transformation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let $U=(u_1,u_2,u_3)$ be a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$, and let $A$ be a $3\times 3$ matrix such that
$$Au_1=u_2, Au_2=u_3, Au_3=u_1.$$

```
Find the representation of A with respect to U.
```

Comment: That's not a question.

Comment: What is unclear about the assignment? Math.SE is not here to do your homework, but to help you understand.

Answer (score 4):

Let's try to find the first column. That is, if 
$$A = \begin{pmatrix} a_{11} & a_{12} & a_{13} \\ a_{21} & a_{22} & a_{23} \\ a_{31} & a_{32} & a_{33} \end{pmatrix},$$
then let us find $a_{11}$, $a_{21}$, and $a_{31}$. Now, by definition, the way to do that is to take the first vector from your basis, $u_1$, evaluate $A$ on it, and figure out what the coefficients in the basis are. That is,
$$Au_1= a_{11}u_1 + a_{21}u_2 + a_{31}u_3.$$
Can you see what the values for $a_{11}$, $a_{21}$ and $a_{31}$ have to be?

Comment: Very good answer. So long as OP does shows no work of his own, I hope some over-eager user does not post the entire answer...